# When soft keyboard in fragment is viewed the top relative layout is hidden?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Like below shown image my activity is viewing like second image .How to solve this.

[image]I am facing the issue in when the soft keyboard is pressed the the top relative layout is hidden and recycler view is placed below the relative layout is fully viewed i the screen.How to solve this. I searched all over the stack overflow but the problem was not solved.

The xml code is attached below

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <com.onefitstop.utility.CustomTextViewBold
            android:id="@+id/chat_activity_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white_partial"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/chat_activity"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_voiletlight"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/chat_activity_label"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>


        <include layout="@layout/error_screen"></include>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The included layout  error_screen.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/layoutError">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_error_1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.onefitstop.utility.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtErrorMsg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/error_msg"
                android:textColor="@color/text_voiletlight"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.onefitstop.utility.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Refresh"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
                android:background="@drawable/refresh_button"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post screen shot of what happens.

Comment: And What Do you want to do Write that as well ,

Comment: when the keyboard is pressed the top layout is hidden

Comment: @ Divyesh Patel see updated my question

Comment: it's due to full screen Option is on ,

Comment: @  Drim how can i solve this error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143498/discussion-between-drim-and-prabha-karan).

Comment: Still now issue was not solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your `<activity>` in the Manifest. See more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: i tried this method but the soft keyboard is only viewing the ediitext is not visible

Comment: You can either have one or the other. In one case the top of the screen is hidden and you can see EditText or in the other one, you can see the top of the screen but the keyboard is potentially on top of the EditText.
If you want the user to be able to see the top of the screen AND the EditText you can put your layout in a ScrollView and implement the first case. So like that the user can scroll to see the top of the screen if necessary and the EditText is not hidden.

Comment: Is there any possible method to view the edittext without using the scrollview

Comment: Then how it works in apps like whats app ,hike .In whats app while typing message the edittext and top view are viewing

Comment: In WhatsApp a part of the view disappears when the keyboard is displayed. The top is the Toolbar which is managed differently so it remains.